# Modifying a temporal table in EF Core 6

Tags: ef-core-6.0, temporal-tables

We're using Code First to manage a database that uses temporal tables. After a few migrations I've run into an issue, basically we needed to make a column nullable because the original data dictionary was incorrect.

When I try to run Update-Database it returns an error:

> Setting SYSTEM_VERSIONING to ON failed because column
> 'MyColumn' does not have the same nullability attribute in
> tables 'MYDB.dbo.TableName' and
> 'MYDB.dbo.TableNameHistory'.

It seems as though the migrationBuilder is creating the new column definition, but that is not getting applied to the history table...

In SQL you can just run an ALTER TABLE command and it updates the history table, but I can't find any documentation on modifying temporal tables in EF Core. Everything is just about creating them.

Is there something specific we need to do to make this work, or is this a bug in EF Core 6?

Comment: Not a bug, just not supported natively I guess. Try [this](https://github.com/findulov/EntityFrameworkCore.TemporalTables), mentioned in the [EF-core docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/extensions/).

Comment: Unfortunately that is for EF Core 5, not 6...

Comment: OMG yes, it seems pretty well dead. Surprising they still mention it.

Comment: Probably the only thing you can do is manually add SQL code to generated migration code.